# Why the stackdriver log entry got auto truncated when it exceeds 128 kB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-stackdriver, gcp-stackdriver

My application in Cloudrun is writing a few log entries using Google Cloud Logging (Stackdriver) as a JSON payload. As per documentation, logging limits are up to 256 kb for a log entry. But When I tried to log an entry of size 129 KB, it got auto-truncated and auto-converted to a text payload. While investigating, I noticed the log entries that exceeded 128 kb got auto-truncated and auto-converted to textpayload. How can I get the complete log entry, and why is it auto-truncating though the allowed size is 256 kb?